# Functions on proper subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I can across what may be a misworded question in an intro set theory course I am TAing and want to make sure I am not being very dumb. It asks to prove that if $A \subsetneq S$ is a proper subset of a finite set $S$, then no $f: A \rightarrow S$ can be bijective. It says to do this by showing that either injectivity or surjectivity always fails. But doesn't surjectivity always fail? For it to not fail it would have to not be well-defined. Am I being very dumb or is this a badly worded question?

Comment: Surjectivity indeed always fails. If $S$ is finite and if a function $f: A \to S$ is surjective then $|S|\leq |A|$, yet $A \subsetneq S$ implies $|A| < |S|$.

Comment: It’s true that surjectivity always fails, but how this is to be proved will depend on exactly what definition of *finite* is being used. What definition *are* you using in the course?

Comment: We say a set is finite if it is in bijection with some $\mathbb{N}_n$

Comment: It could be that the question is trying to be explicit per the definition of "bijection:" (Quoting from wikipedia:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Special_types_of_binary_relations):  "A bijection:  A function that is injective and surjective".  So, technically speaking showing one or the other to be always false makes the "AND" statement always false.  Just a speculation as to what is motivating the wording in the question.  I hope this helps.